# Lua File System DLL Not Valid

Tags: eclipse, lua, luafilesystem

Pretty new to the LUA environment, so hopefully i'm just missing something really small. I've been trying to compile LuaFileSystem using LuaRocks and MinGW. After having finally compiled it, I am trying to load the DLL using

```
require("lfs")
```

and

```
local f = assert(package.loadlib("lfs.dll","lfs"))
lfs = f()
```

And I keep getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.naef.jnlua.LuaRuntimeException: error loading module 'lfs' from file '.\lfs.dll':
    %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_pcall(Native Method)
    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.call(LuaState.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.run(JNLua51Launcher.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.main(JNLua51Launcher.java:143)
```

A couple points to note is that I'm trying to utilize this DLL in the Eclipse LDT Interpreter. The DLL is compiled against LUA 5.1 and Eclipse is using LUA 5.1. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the same `require("lfs")` work from a regular Lua interpreter?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks for the comment, got me to rethink why it failed (see answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, I failed to realize that the LDT for Eclipse includes an embedded version of Lua based on jnLua. Using LuaRocks, I compiled against the included version with LuaRocks which is more vanilla lua.

I'm sure there's a way to resolve this by setting LuaRocks to use the jnLua interpreter, but the quicker method was just to add the LuaRocks included version as the interpreter used in Eclipse.

In Preferences, Lua->Interpreters, Add a new one. For the executable just navigated to the included LuaRocks Lua interpreter (lua5.1.exe). Once I updated my run profiles to use this new interpreter, it worked fine.